# 時間の切り上げ・切り下げをしたい

Tags: excel, google-spreadsheet

出退勤のデータを切り上げ、切り下げしたいです。

30分単位で切り上げなどを行いたいのですが、
勤務時間帯が下記となっており、休憩時間が70分なので退勤時間がきれいな単位で区切られません。

勤務時間帯：8:30～17:40

【例】
出勤：8:01 　　→8:30と表示させたい
退勤：17:41　　→17:40と表示させたい

出勤：8:29 　　→8:30と表示させたい
退勤：18:09　　→17:40と表示させたい

出勤：8:30 　　→8:30と表示させたい
退勤：18:10　　→18:10と表示させたい

出勤：8:31 　　→9:00と表示させたい
退勤：18:11　　→18:10と表示させたい

調べてみたのですが、CEILINGやFLOOR関数を使えば切り上げ・切り下げができるようですが、
任意の時間から30分単位での切り上げ・切り下げなどは調べてもわかりませんでした。
何かアドバイスいただけますとありがたいです。

以上よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 答えとは関係無いのですが、その処理はやらない方が良いと思われます。[残業代の15分・30分単位で計算・切り捨ては違法｜理由と対処法を詳しく解説](https://roudou-pro.com/columns/213/)

Answer (score 0):

IF関数とAND関数で、条件式を作ればできそうです。

=IF(H1<TIME(8,30,0),"8:30",IF(AND(H1>=TIME(8,31,0),H1<TIME(9,1,0)),"9:00"))

=IF(H2<TIME(18,10,0),"17:40",IF(AND(H2>=TIME(18,10,0)),"18:10"))

Comment: yn95ny様
ご回答ありがとうございます。
確かにIF関数とAND関数を組み合わせればできそうです！
けれど、私の記載が足りていなかった部分が大いにありますが、8時間勤務であり、必ず8:30出社とは限りませんので、すべての出社時間を考慮しなければならなさそうです。

Answer (score 0):

> 休憩時間が70分なので退勤時間がきれいな単位で区切られません。

1. `出勤時刻`を切り上げる
2. `退勤時刻 - 出勤時刻 - 休憩時間`の`勤務時間`を算出
3. `勤務時間`を切り下げる
4. `出勤時刻 + 勤務時間 + 休憩時間`で`退勤時刻`を算出

とかどうでしょう。

Comment: sayuri様
ご回答ありがとうございます。
私にはなかった発想で目からうろこでございます。
こちらも後で試してみようと思います。ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 0):

```
出勤　=TIME(HOUR(A1),CEILING(MINUTE(A1),30),0)

退勤　=TIME(HOUR(A2),FLOOR(MINUTE(A2)-10,30)+10,0)
```

Comment: mir様
ご回答ありがとうございます。
こちらで出来そうです！すべての出勤時間試してみようと思います。
ありがとうございます。